# elastic search unable to get entire data from oracle DB with JDBC plugin

Tags: oracle, elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack, ojdbc

I'm new to elastic.
have an oracle DB, I'm trying to index the entire data into elastic search.
nce configured the query, elastic is not retrieving the entire DB, but just a couple of records. (Total should be at least 200+)

i'm haven't setup an index mapping by myself.

below my conf file:

```
input {
  jdbc {
    jdbc_driver_library => "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/jars/ojdbc14.jar"
    jdbc_driver_class => "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
    jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:oracle:thin:@ip:port/db"
    jdbc_user => "user"
    jdbc_password => "pwd"
    clean_run => true
    record_last_run => false
    statement_filepath => "/etc/logstash/queries/archived.sql"
    schedule => "0 * * * *"
  }
}filter {
  mutate {
    remove_field => ["@version", "@timestamp"]
  }
}output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["http://127.0.0.1:9200"]
    index => "archive-2022-09-22"
    action => "index"
    document_id => "%{id}"
    user => "user"
    password => "pwd"
  }
}
```

my statement file:

```
select * from archive
```

from logstash logs i cannot retrieve any useful informations:

```
[2022-11-23T15:11:24,811][ERROR][logstash.licensechecker.licensereader] Unable to retrieve license information from license server {:message=>"No Available connections"}
[2022-11-23T15:11:54,808][ERROR][logstash.licensechecker.licensereader] Unable to retrieve license information from license server {:message=>"No Available connections"}
[2022-11-23T15:12:00,398][INFO ][logstash.inputs.jdbc     ][archived][f085843c850992c12e03ee486c086aea9dfd8655b67ab23879b5f69e3fa8f1d5] (0.013649s) select * from archive

[2022-11-23T15:12:24,808][ERROR][logstash.licensechecker.licensereader] Unable to retrieve license information from license server {:message=>"No Available connections"}
[2022-11-23T15:12:54,808][ERROR][logstash.licensechecker.licensereader] Unable to retrieve license information from license server {:message=>"No Available connections"}
[2022-11-23T15:13:00,134][INFO ][logstash.inputs.jdbc     ][archived][f085843c850992c12e03ee486c086aea9dfd8655b67ab23879b5f69e3fa8f1d5] (0.013788s) select * from archive
```

i have no clue what to look for, any suggestions?

Comment: How do you know that only some records are inserted?

Comment: because if i perform the same query when connected to db (select * from archive;) i've got as a result= 249 rows selected.. Instead when performed by kibana/elastic only few records are in elastic :|

Comment: How do you know how many documents are inserted in Elastic? I am asking, because if you do a default search only the first ten documents are returned.

Comment: because apart of the lenses i have created that displays no data, i can confirm partially data when i go in the discover section. Only a few records are present there.

Comment: Can you got to kibana dev tool and execute `GET archive-2022-09-22/_search` and see what value it is showing for `total` ?

Answer (score 0):

i found the issue.
in logstash.conf file, index field:

```
index => "archive-2022-09-22"
```

was continuously overwritten by the execution of the next query schedule.
because i have needed as well to change my input source (still a sql statement but executed and formatted through an exernal container) i mapped as well the index file to a variable that will take place of the current date.

thank you so much for your help :)